# How to share file on local network with specific computer and not with all

Tags: windows, sharing

I have a desktop computer and two laptops, laptop 1 and laptop 2.
I created a home network on windows 1o and shared a folder on my desktop pc, so both of laptops can see that folder.

**I would like to know, how to share folder only with specific computer on same network?**

I heard that if you want to share folder to specific computer(for example laptop 1 and not to laptop 2), you have to create the same user account on a local computer as on laptop 1.

**So if my laptop 1 has only one user Aleksey who is administrator, how to create that same user on local computer so i can share that folder only with laptop 1?** (Aleksey administrator is not created with microsoft or email).

Answer (score 0):

First of all the way you are trying to solve the problem is wrong because a local user “User1” on a computer “PC1” is not the same as local user “User1” on  another computer PC2. Even if the user name is same these are completely different users. 
You can only achieve such user based permissions if both the machines are in a domain ( active directory) and you log on to both the machines using a domain user account.

The better way to solve your problem is to simply use static IP addressing and using firewall to block SMB ( CIFS) traffic from specific IP addresses. If I remember correctly you should block traffic on 139 port and it should solve the problem. If you are running latest Windows 10 then you may need to block additional port such as 445 as the higher version of SMB seems to be using 445 port. If you do not need to access any other services from the same computer then just block access to all ports for that remote address.

Comment: So you think this is the easiest way if i want to share file only to specific computer on a network?

Answer (score 0):

The way you could do this, for instance if I was to browse to another computer on the same network using \PCRemote\c$ in Windows explorer and hit enter, you should get prompted for the credentials to authenticate against that remote pc. User Field = ".\local account on remote pc" and then the password, you should then have been authenticated against the local account stored locally on the remote PC. Hope that makes sense.